# What component to use for creating side-by-side comparison of beans?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to compare multiple beans [side-by-side](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=6639&idPhone2=6033), i.e. one column with list of properties, followed by an *arbitrary* number of columns with values. Please note that the number of properties is not fixed.

Here is what the bean looks like:

```
public class GraphicsCard {

    private String brand;    // e.g. 'Asus'
    private String name;     // e.g. 'GTX770'
    private Map<String, Float> performanceStats; // arbitrary number of properties and their
                                                 // values, e.g. ('cores', 230), ('price', '
    // getters, setters...
}
```

And this is how it is supposed to look like on the page:

```
             Asus gtx460    MSI gtx970      Palit gt770   
cores     |     320      |    420        |    312       | 
frequency |     500      |    1600       |    1300      | 
memory    |     1024     |    4096       |    1024      | 
power     |     90       |    80         |    110       |
```

What I already managed to do (which I also needed) is, by creating a ColumnModel class:

```
class GraphicsCardColumnModel implements Serializable {

    private String header;
    private String property;

    public GraphicsCardColumnModel(String header, String property) {
        this.header = header;
        this.property = property;
    }
    // getters, setters...
}
```

And using this code on the .xhtml page:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="card" value="#{graphicsCardsBean.listOfCards}">

    <p:column headerText="#{'brand'}">
        <h:outputText value="#{card.brand}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{'name'}">
        <h:outputText value="#{card.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:columns value="#{graphicsCardsBean.listOfCardColumnModels}" 
    sortBy="#{card.performanceStats[selectedModel.property]}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            #{selectedModel.header}
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{card.performanceStats[selectedModel.property]}" />
    </p:columns>

</p:dataTable>
```

to create a table that looks like:

```
brand | name | cores | frequency | memory | power            
-------------------------------------------------            
Asus  |gtx460| 320   |   500     |  1024  | 90 
MSI   |gt610 | 210   |   230     |  512   | 60   
MSI   |gtx970| 420   |   1600    |  4096  | 80
Asus  |gtx980| 660   |   1200    |  5120  | 90
Palit |gt770 | 312   |   1300    |  1024  | 110
```

which works great. But now I need also a different presentation. Would there be any better option than p:dataTable to use for this case? If not, could you suggest a solution with p:dataTable. Although it could be helpful, you don't have to write code, just suggest an idea. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention, columns (i.e. graphics cards) should be able to change (e.g. instead of "Asus gtx460" user chooses "Palit gtx460"). Then, the table should be able to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ui:repeat>` (from `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"`) lets you use any native HTML element while iterating over your `#{graphicsCardsBean.listOfCards}`

Example :

```
<ui:repeat value="#{graphicsCardsBean.listOfCards}" var="card">
     <SOMEHTMLTAG>
          <h:outputText value="#{card.name}" />
     </SOMEHTMLTAG>
</ui:repeat>
```

**EDIT :**

Here's a solution.

You need to add a list of strings to your controller populated with every performance category (core, memory...). Then with `<ui:repeat>` you access each card, and with a second `<ui:repeat>` you iterate over each category.

View (same as your second output) :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.performancesCategories}" var="category">
        <th>
          <h:outputText value="#{category}" />
        </th>
      </ui:repeat>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.listOfCards}" var="card">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h:outputText value="#{card.brand} #{card.name}" />
        </td>
        <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.performancesCategories}" var="category">
          <td>
            <h:outputText value="#{card.performanceStats.get(category)}" />
          </td>
        </ui:repeat>
      </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

OR

View (same as your first output) :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.listOfCards}" var="card">
        <th>
          <h:outputText value="#{card.brand} #{card.name}" />
        </th>
      </ui:repeat>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.performancesCategories}" var="category">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h:outputText value="#{category}" />
        </td>
        <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.listOfCards}" var="card">
          <td>
            <h:outputText value="#{card.performanceStats.get(category)}" />
          </td>
        </ui:repeat>
      </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller :

```
public List<String> performancesCategories;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    performancesCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    for (GraphicsCard card : listOfCards) {
        for (String perf : card.getPerformanceStats().keySet()) {
            if (!performancesCategories.contains(perf)) {
                performancesCategories.add(perf);
            }
        }
    }
}

public List<String> getPerformancesCategories() {
    return performancesCategories;
}

public void setPerformancesCategories(List<String> performancesCategories) {
    this.performancesCategories = performancesCategories;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I am not sure how to combine column for property names with columns for property values from beans.

Comment: @MikeJohnson See updated answer. I put 2 solutions for your view, matching the 2 outputs you presented in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thrax for this answer. This does work as intended. I have just wrapped everything in h:panelGroup and now data can be updated, according to my edit. I just thought there would be a way around it with some component, e.g. dataTable. Thanks